# Retrieving keys and values from json

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON string:

```
$json= '{"data":[{"id":"123","name":"john smith","gender":"MALE","phone":[{"number":"+919999999999","numberType":"MOBILE"}]}]}'
```

I want to retrieve all the values and keys from the json, output should look like:

```
id:         123
name:       john smith
gender:     MALE
phone:
    number:     +919999999999
    numberType: MOBILE
```

I have tried this code but it fails to get the phone output:

```
$jsond = json_decode($json);
foreach($jsond->data as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $key => $val)
    {
        echo $key . ': ' . $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we allowed to refactor your json. Or, please demonstrate more than one person represented in your data.

Comment: Hey @Jonathan the output will be of only single person only according to request and yes we are allowed to refactor

Comment: Related: [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) is for:

```
<?php

$json = '{"data":[{"id":"123","name":"john smith","gender":"MALE","phone":[{"number":"+919999999999","numberType":"MOBILE"}]}]}';

$jsond = json_decode($json,true);

function test_print($val, $key)
{
    echo "$key : $val<br/>\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($jsond, 'test_print');
```

Resulting in this output:

```html
id : 123<br/>
name : john smith<br/>
gender : MALE<br/>
number : +919999999999<br/>
numberType : MOBILE<br/>
```